# Mega drop down or product list shown directly in home page?

Tags: dropdown, homepage

We proposed a classic structure for a big brand website: Horizontal navigation menu, big slider with images and three boxes for highligts (img 1) Product list is shown with a mega drop down menu.

My client is now asking me to show the whole list of product lines (12) directly in home page (AS SHOWN IN IMG 2) and she suggests to show them directly at the top of the page, right after the navigation menu...

Do you have a better solution? How do I deal with the drop down? Do you know similar solutions?

[image: img 1 and img 2].

Comment: what is the problem with the 2nd solution? I have seen websites that had similar layouts. My question would be where is the logo?

Comment: The logo is on the header section, these wireframes are a sketch I just did right now to show you the two solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

Funny how you mention it right now - I saw it for the first time on tuesday - linked from chat. The image is from [Moonfruit.com](http://www.moonfruit.com/).

[image]

The pattern is IMHO very intuitive - so I'd go with it.

Comment: Thank you, this can be very useful. However I still have the drop down menu... what should I do with that? Should I keep both? drop down and products on slider?

Comment: @Giults I'd lose the Mega-Drop-Down menu and only use product tiles. But there's nothing wrong in keeping it either. It's a matter of personal prefference!